# No Anaconda Navigator after installing (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda

I installed "Anaconda 2019.03 for Windows" but there is no Navigator. I already read all Posts to this common Anaconda-problem, but nothing worked. It seems as if there is no Navigator installed. Also, I can’t use "conda" or "anaconda" although i set the environment variables.

Since I already tried the installation process various times and nothing on the internet was of any help, I would be happy if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I resolved it by changing the download path from my user profile which was FirstLast(Company). To just the C: drive.

I believe this was caused by the "()" as Anaconda says:

> Note
>
> Install Anaconda to a directory path that does not contain spaces or
> unicode characters.
> https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

Comment: I tried that as well, but didn't work. Meanwhile i newly setup the whole machine an now it works ^^